# How to list all registered events of a DOM node using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I can add or remove an event handler for a DOM node. Is it possible to find out all the registered events handlers of a given DOM node? I am referring to straight Javascript meaning no frameworks or toolkits like jQuery, dojo, Prototype, GWT, etc. If the answer is no, any reason why? Security issues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have any browsers implemented the DOM3 EventListenerList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810534/have-any-browsers-implemented-the-dom3-eventlistenerlist)

Comment: A question asked more than 2 years ago is a duplicate of one asked two days ago?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but just in case, for chrome you can use **getEventListeners**

[getEventListeners function](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#getEventListeners-function)

as mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17466308/538752

Answer (score 4):

DOM Level 3 specifies [eventListenerList](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20020208/changes.html) - however, I'm not aware of any DOM implementation which supports this - or any other reliable way to list the event listeners. It seems to have been an oversight to this point.

Comment: DOM Level 3 doesn't define eventListenerList (you're linking to a draft from 2002). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810534/have-any-browsers-implemented-the-dom3-eventlistenerlist/7814692#7814692

Comment: @Nickolay Indeed - it's incredibly disappointing to see that the WG can't see the use cases for the API, but thanks for pointing out that it has been removed.

Comment: Please update this answer wrt the "specification". I had to read a comment to be [re]disappointed.

Answer (score 3):

This works for Chrome/Safari console:

```
getEventListeners(document.getElementByID('myElementId'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) can show you which events are registered, but it only works with DOM level 0 attached events; the W3C level 2 implementation as well as the Internet Explorer proprietary method are not supported and/or cannot be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

If your interest is to discover some event, in order to disable it - I came here because of that - I recommend to use the Firebug extension, with Mozilla Firefox. Selecting the part of the document, you are interested in, look at the right panel, the Events tab: you will see all events, and can even disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in **Google Chrome**, please select the element and notice the number, it will show you **$0** or any other number.

Then in console, type this code and press enter.

```
getEventListeners($0)
```

and then you will see the result. Please see the image below for more elaboration.

[image: Google Console showing getEventListeners result]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, landed here, and didn't find an useful answer.

In case you can execute script **before** `addEventListener` calls from other parties, you might do something really dirty like:

```
var obj = something; // Your DOM element you want to watch

var beforeAddEvent = obj.addEventListener;
obj.addEventListener = function() {
  // Do something with arguments here (like storing in an array)
  // arguments[0]: event name
  // arguments[1]: Listener function
  // arguments[3]: eventual options passed

  // If you don't call this, the event listener won't even be attached, it might be also useful in some case
  beforeAddEvent.apply(obj, arguments);
};
```