# how to get list of all registered synthetic event handlers/listeners for a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, event-listener

```
var Rc = <MyReactComponent 
  onChange={(e) => {console.log(e);} 
  onClick={(e) => { workIt(); }} />;
```

How do I get the list of listeners ['onChange', 'onClick'], for component Rc.

I see questions related to finding listeners on DOM nodes... [How to find event listeners on a DOM node using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940104/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-using-javascript); for which apparently no simple call exists like getEventLiteners(), alongside addEventListener() is DOM DOES support.

Is there a clean and easy way to get the listeners for React Component?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any in-built way to do this in React, however you can create a simple function to do this for you:

```
// Build a mapping of event listeners
const getListeners = component => {
    return Object.fromEntries(
       Object
           .entries(component.props) // Get the props
           .filter(([key, value]) => key.startsWith("on")) // Filter event listeners
    );
};

const foo = <SomeComponent
    onChange={(e) => {console.log(e);} 
    onClick={(e) => { workIt(); }}
/>;

console.log("listeners", getListeners(foo));
// { onChange: f, onClick: f }
```

In this case, we filter all props with `getListeners` that start with "on" because every event listener in React starts with "on".

You could make this more robust by explicitly filtering on the actual supported event listeners in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#reference
And also filtering the value of each prop to make sure it is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the same interface as the browser’s native event, including stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work identically across all browsers.

**Supported Events**
React normalizes events so that they have consistent properties across different browsers.

The event handlers below are triggered by an event in the bubbling phase. To register an event handler for the capture phase, append Capture to the event name; for example, instead of using onClick, you would use onClickCapture to handle the click event in the capture phase.

1.Clipboard Events
2.Composition Events
3.Keyboard Events
4.Focus Events
5.Form Events
6.Generic Events
7.Mouse Events
8.Pointer Events
9.Selection Events
10.Touch Events
11.UI Events
12.Wheel Events
13.Media Events
14.Image Events
15.Animation Events
16.Transition Events

Also You Can Create An OnChange Event Like That:

```js
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <input name="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}

export default App;
```