# How can we find all the events attached to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

We need to find all the events attached to a particular DOM element. For example, how can I find all the events attached to the YouTube search input tag? I have tried:

```
$._data( $("#tabieBrowser")[0], "events" );
```

It works on some website but mostly it doesn't. I have also tried to include jQuery if the website doesn't have it.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I suppose you don't mean *events*, but *event handlers*, right?

Comment: I don't think there is a reliable way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18116524/11342676

Comment: Yes all event handlers @trincot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find event listeners on a DOM node using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940104/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome only, you can use `getEventListeners(element)` to find all active event listeners and the events they are listening for.